# Inner join doesn't work with PDO and fetch assoc

Tags: php, pdo

For my news en post comment system I can't get the query get results from 2 tables (tbl_news and tbl_comments). In another program I made with mysqli the inner join worked but now this time with PDO I can't get it to work.

This is my code:

```
$newsQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * 
                           FROM tbl_news 
                           INNER JOIN tbl_comments ON tbl_news.news_id = tbl_comments.news_id
                           ORDER BY news_id DESC 
                           LIMIT 5");

$newsQuery -> execute();

while($newsFetch = $newsQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

echo "<div class='news-post'><h3 class='post-title'>" . $newsFetch->title . "</h3>
        <p style='float:left'>By: <span class='post-author'>" . $newsFetch->author . "</span></p>
        <p style='float:right'>Date: <span class='post-date' style='font-style:italic;'>" . $newsFetch->date . "</span></p>
        <br><p>" . $newsFetch->text . "</p></div>";
        if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && ($newsFetch->comments == '1')) {
            echo "Comments(";
            echo "<div id='commentClick'>Click <a href='#' id='openForm'>here</a> to post a comment</div>";
            echo "<form class='navbar-form' id='commentForm'><input style='margin-right:5px' type='text' size='80%' name='commentText' placeholder='Type your comment here'><input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' value='Send'></form>";
        }elseif(!isset($_SESSION['user']) && ($newsFetch->comments == '1')) {
            echo "Click here to view comments. If you want to post comments please login first";
        }else{
            echo "Comments are disabled for this news item";
        }
}
```

In the database I have the following values:
in tbl_news there is a news_id and in tbl_comments are comment_id, news_id and user_id.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be more specific than saying it doesnt work.It is as helpful as me answering you have errors.

Comment: This is the error: [14-Dec-2014 06:07:27 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'news_id' in order clause is ambiguous' in /home/mikeoerl/public_html/index.php:32
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mikeoerl/public_html/index.php(32): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/mikeoerl/public_html/index.php on line 32

Comment: The query worked with just "SELECT * FROM tbl_news". But I also need to add the comments in the same fetch_obj

Comment: You have a column with the same name in both tables,you need to specify the table name before that column.Replace `select *` with `SELECT col1,col2,tbl_news.news_id,tbl_comments.news_id,...` for the column in question.

Comment: Didn't I do that then? tbl_news.news_id = tbl_comments.news_id

Comment: That is a JOIN condition,you need to specify in the select

Comment: I now made this query but it still does not work:
$newsQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT tbl_news.news_id, tbl_news.date, tbl_news.author, tbl_news.text, tbl_news.date, tbl_news.comments, tbl_comments.comment_id, tbl_comments.news_id, tbl_comments.user_id, tbl_comments.comment FROM tbl_news INNER JOIN tbl_comments ON tbl_news.news_id = tbl_comments.news_id ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 5");

Comment: Thanks now it does something. But now it only shows the latest news item and not the last 5

Comment: Maybe because there is only 1 comment in the database?

Comment: But without the inner join on tbl_comments it DID display 5 database entries

Comment: I see not it does only display something when there is a comment_id (with news_id) linked to a comment. So thats why it only shows 1 news item because there is only 1 comment

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN if you want all rows FROM tbl_news no matter how many comments in tbl_comments

Comment: Thank you very much. That does the job! Now on to the next mission to count rows for each comment to display (x) comments

Comment: Could it be that due to the LEFT JOIN that it now only shows the news_id in de fetch if a news item has more than 0 comments?

Comment: Because I want to post the news_id in a form to submit the comment. But it won't display any of the news_id's anymore. Only of the 1 which has 1 comment. The other news items do appear but without news_id

Comment: I think somehow it's only looking for news_id's in the tbl_comments now and there is only that 1. How can I specify to look for the news_id in tbl_news with $newsFetch->news_id(???)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use alias for your database table names, ex:

```
SELECT n.*, c.* FROM tbl_news n 
INNER JOIN tbl_comments c ON n.news_id = c.news_id 
ORDER BY n.news_id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: he doesn't need the prefix in the `SELECT` clause, since he wants columns from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner join query should be like this

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

I mean you need to specify the tablename.columnname instead of using all (*)

**EDIT**

```
  1052 Column 'news_id' in order clause is ambiguous'
```

This error happens when you are joining 2 or more tables in a statement and there are columns among these tables that have the same name and you didn’t prefix the column name with the table name when referencing the column in your statement.

Comment: Would it have been so hard for you to use the tables from his actual query?

Comment: I want to have access to all the rows in both tables tbl_news and tbl_comments